# How to eliminate the frame of a ComboBox DropDownList

Tags: delphi, drop-down-menu, combobox

The problem is that I can not find any option to hide or eliminate or color the black frame of the DropDownList of a ComboBox.

I tried `Windows.GetComboBoxInfo(ComboBox.Handle, CBI)` and I can get the CBI properties. But I can't find out how to use this for solving my problem.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't have a black frame on mine - I have a blue frame. It's drawn by the OS. Can you provide a screenshot and tells us which OS/Version you're using?

Comment: I am working on WindowsXP and Windows 8. I think that it don't matters if the frame is black or blue. I want a white frame or no frame at all. Like you say: this frame is drawn by the OS. I don't want to reconfigure the OS. I want to solve the problem within my delphi-application.

Comment: No, it doesn't matter if it's black or blue, but that was just to understand that we need to be clear on the OS. Each version of Windows has a slightly different way of drawing. For all we know, you could have been using FMX on MacOS. But in any case, the drop-down menu is technically a separate window. If I recall, this consists of getting that window handle and making some WinAPI calls to remove the border from the window. As far as which API calls is beyond me. Someone else can surely chime in with more specifics.

Comment: You are right. The solution is:                                SetWindowLong(aCBI.hwndList, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(aCBI.hwndList, GWL_STYLE ) and not WS_CAPTION);                                                                                                             It took me hours to find it out. It's the same as if you want to get a window without a frame.

Comment: Cool, feel free to contribute your own answer below. Be sure to make it in a way that it can be helpful to future readers who want to do the same thing, and it will have my vote.

Comment: @m c: Well, but this *is* about "[getting] a window without a frame"! :)